# Debugger stops on core data save but no error output

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a simple method that just takes two managed object IDs, pulls the managedObjects for them, makes a relation and then saves them into the managedObjectContext.

When I perform the save on the managedObjectContext, the debugger stops on the save line with an objc_exception_throw referencing the nsmanagedObjectContext save.  Although there is no output in the nserror object that is output to give me any details as to why an exception is thrown.  It also appears as if this save does work fine, which makes this even more confusing.

Here is the method in question...

```
- (void)relateLocationToInvite:(NSManagedObjectID *)locationID :(NSManagedObjectID *)inviteID {
NSManagedObject *invite = [self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:inviteID];
NSManagedObject *locationObj = [self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:locationID];
Location *location = (Location *)locationObj;

[invite setValue:location forKey:@"location"];
NSError *error = nil;
if( ![self.managedObjectContext save:&error] ){
    NSLog(@"Error relating a location to an invite %@",error);
}
```

}

Comment: If indeed the exception is being thrown from somewhere in the Core Data stack, the `error` variable may well have not had a chance to get set. Errors are returned in circumstances like validation failures, but if you hit an internal inconsistency error or suchlike, that will throw an exception without writing anything meaningful to the error object.

Comment: If you haven't got one already, you could set up an Exception Breakpoint to try to catch the exception when it's created, rather than waiting for it to be thrown. This may give you greater context of the crash-to-be. You can also use the `bt` command in the debug console to get a stack trace of the failure. This is just general advice, since it's difficult to tell what might be going wrong without more knowledge of your project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the execution of the application continues after the `save:` method without any problem (i.e. without throwing any uncaught exception and without reporting any error), that means the saving operation's implementation has caught the exception and decided to silently ignore it.

Why this happens is unclear: maybe the implementation relies on exceptions to report internal errors (this is not the way Objective-C exceptions should be used but some other languages make more use of exceptions). As long as the exception is caught before it reaches your own code, you should not worry about it.

If you want to know the reason of the exception, you may break on `objc_exception_throw` and use the following debugger command:

```
po *(id *)($ebp + 8)
```

This will display the `NSException *` parameter given to the function in the iOS Simulator (x86 architecture). On the device (arm architecture), the same result can be achieved using (if my memory serves my correctly):

```
po $r0
```

Comment: Is it safe to ignore this then? btw, it can be triggered by updating an object that was already deleted from the persistent store by another context.